# Group Nestest Object To Array MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregate, lookup

So right now I have data like this and I'm using the query like in the playground to get it https://mongoplayground.net/p/f6-dVy0Exja

The problem is when I group the commentReply there seems to be no problem but when I group the commentReplySection I can't keep the main commentSection of them. I want the commentReply to be a group of array depending on their main comment instead of a separate object.

Expected Result https://mongoplayground.net/p/IfjT1RozLRr

AnyOne having any Idea to help me please.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you be more clear on what you are asking? Describe more about your document, and what you want, your link give a vague idea.

Comment: After your first stage (`"$project"`), the only thing that survives is `"_id"`.  I'm confident you don't want that.